# Creating and handling subcollection in a document in firestore with Kotlin

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

How are subcollections created in kotlin and how are data retrieved, updated, and deleted?
I couldn't find any documentation describing subcollections in Kotlin.
Can you explain it as code in kotlin?

[This is how the firestore shape I want to make.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vn3eV.png)

I managed to save to Firebase, but I couldn't figure out how to pull the data.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

To read from, write to, or query a collection you need to create a reference to that collection. For a top-level collection you do that with (based on the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#kotlin+ktx_5)):

```
val db = Firebase.firestore

val colRef = db.collection("cities");
```

Then to get a reference to document in there, you do:

```
val docRef = db.collection("cities").document("SF")
```

Now to get a reference to a subcollection under that document, you do:

```
val subcolRef = db.collection("cities").document("SF").collection("sites")
```

At that point, you can use the normal operation to query or read from the collection reference.

Comment: I managed to save to Firebase, but I couldn't figure out how to pull the data.